# Python Bulk Blank folder creation

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to create bulk folders based on simple text file. `os.makedir` helps to create new folder but i am not sure how to incorporate with newpath variable along with folder list. following is what i am trying with. I understand that code has syntax error. So need some help to correct/enhance the code.

```
import os.path  
newpath = r'C:\Program Files\test\'  
with open('folders.txt') as f:  
    for line in f:  
        ff = os.makedirs(newpath,line.strip())  
        ff.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
import os, sys
newpath = 'C:\Program Files\test'
with open(open('folders.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    newdir = os.path.join(newpath, line.strip())
    try:
      os.makedirs(newdir)
    except OSError:  # if makedirs() failed
      sys.stderr.write("ERR: Could not create %s\n" % newdir)
      pass  # continue with next line
```

Notes:

- Use [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to combine a paths. This will automatically use separators that are suitable for your OS.
- [`os.makedirs()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) does not return anything
- `os.makedirs()` will raise an [`OSError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError) exception if the directory already exists or cannot be created.

Comment: if i am not using '\\' i am getting SyntaxError ' EOL while scanning string literal' wondering if there is any tweak so i can use path with '\'.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870730/python-raw-strings-and-trailing-backslash. For a quick solution, just skip the last slash (`r'C:\Program Files\test'`). `os.path.join()` will still do the right thing. Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

Use [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join path components.

```
import os.path  
newpath = r'C:\Program Files\test\'  
with open('folders.txt') as f:  
    for line in f:  
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(newpath, line.strip()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use os.path.join function documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html).