# Using a raw string with os.walk()

Tags: python, os.walk

I'm trying to get os.walk() to work in a program I'm working on, but I keep getting the error:
ValueError: invalid \x escape

From looking around online, I've seen that the error can arise from not using a raw string.
However, I still keep getting the error...

```
import os
path = r'D:\Data\Tracking\'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    print root
    print dirs
    print files
```

Anyone have an idea of what I can do differently to make it work?

Comment: Can you post the complete error message and full traceback?

Comment: I believe that the backslash still escapes quotes in a string, so drop the last backslash. See also the syntax highlighting here, which highlights this mistake. Where the exact error comes from is probably in the part of the code not shown.

Comment: `path = r'D:\Data\Tracking'`. ``\'`` is the root of evil

Comment: Why don't you simply use forward slashes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python raw strings and trailing backslash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870730/python-raw-strings-and-trailing-backslash)

Comment: So, I was commenting out a large section of my code using '''.
I guess that is bad, because python recognizes the triple quotes as doc tools.  I thought the triple quote commented everything out.  
Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little surprised that you're getting a `ValueError`... but notice that the problem is with the trailing `'`.

```
>>> path = r'D:\Data\Tracking'
>>> path = r'D:\Data\Tracking\'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    path = r'D:\Data\Tracking\'
                              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

For workarounds, see [Why can't a raw string end in an odd number of trailing backslashes](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash)

My favorite is:

```
>>> path = r'D:\Data\Tracking' '\\'
```

which uses automagic string concatenation of literals.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `\\` to prevent the last backslash from escaping the quote after it.

```
>>> path = r'D:\Data\Tracking\'
  File "<input>", line 1
    path = r'D:\Data\Tracking\'
                              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> path = r'D:\Data\Tracking\\'
>>> print(path)
D:\Data\Tracking\\
```

You can do this without a raw string to get the exact string that you want:

```
>>> path = 'D:\\Data\Tracking\\'
>>> print(path)
D:\Data\Tracking\
```