# Python : Trying to concatenate a simple string into a URL

Tags: python

I've a variable "title" that I've scraped from a website page that I want to use as the file name. 
I've tried many combinations to no avail. What is wrong with my code?

```
f1 = open(r'E:\Dp\Python\Yt\' + str(title) + '.txt', 'w')
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax highlighting in the question should help you out. A `\'` does not terminate the string -- it is an escaped single tick `'`.

As [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870730/python-raw-strings-and-trailing-backslash) shows, it is actually impossible to end a raw string with a backslash. Your best option is to use string formatting

```
# old-style string interpolation
open((r'E:\Dp\Python\Yt\%s.txt' % title), 'w')
# or str.format, which is VASTLY preferred in any modern Python
open(r'E:\Dp\Python\Yt\{}.txt'.format(title), 'w')
# or, in Python 3.6+, the new-hotness of f-strings
open(rf'E:\Dp\Python\Yt\{title}.txt', 'w')
```

Or else add even more string concatenation, which seems measurably worse.

```
open(r'E:\Dp\Python\Yt' + "\\" + str(title) + '.txt', 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to escape all them slashes boyo, otherwise they will be escaping the characters that follow.

```
f1 = open(r'E:\\Dp\\Python\\Yt\\' + str(title) + '.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: Nope, that's what the raw string is for (note the preceding `r` in front of the string's quotes)