# EOL while scanning string literal syntax error

Tags: python

My code throws an exception

```py
path='E:\programming_section\data_science_and_ml\kist\six_sem_project\alImdb '
positiveFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(path+"train\pos\") if x.endswith(".txt")]
negativeFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(path+"train\neg\") if x.endswith(".txt")]
testFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(path+"test\") if x.endswith(".txt")]
```

The exception:

```py
    SyntaxError: **EOL while scanning string literal
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You cannot end a string with a single trailing slash, e.g. `"train\pos\"`. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870730/python-raw-strings-and-trailing-backslash)

Answer (score -1):

Always remember that slashes behave differently from most other symbols in strings. Slashes in python usually are for making special characters. With that said always remember that you cannot end python string with `\` slashes, what you want to do is either escape it or make it a raw string since it is a path.
For a raw string you should have something like this

```
path='E:\programming_section\data_science_and_ml\kist\six_sem_project\alImdb '
positiveFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(path+r"train\pos\") if x.endswith(".txt")]
negativeFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(path+r"train\neg\") if x.endswith(".txt")]
testFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(path+r"test\") if x.endswith(".txt")]
```

But if you decide to go with escaping the slashes then

```
path='E:\programming_section\data_science_and_ml\kist\six_sem_project\alImdb '
positiveFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(path + "train\pos" + "\\") if x.endswith(".txt")]
negativeFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(path + "train\neg" + "\\") if x.endswith(".txt")]
testFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(path + "test" + "\\") if x.endswith(".txt")]
```

You could also consider using the os.path.join

```
path='E:\programming_section\data_science_and_ml\kist\six_sem_project\alImdb '
positiveFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(os.path.join(path + "train\pos") if x.endswith(".txt")]
negativeFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(os.path.join(path + "train\neg")) if x.endswith(".txt")]
testFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(os.path.join(path + "test")) if x.endswith(".txt")]
```

Personally i would recommend the raw string option

Comment: OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'E:\\programming_section\\data_science_and_ml\\kist\\six_sem_project\x07lImdb train\\pos\\'
using this follwing error occured

Comment: Which is why i recommended using the raw string version. You could also consider using the `os.path.join()` function