# Including a backslash at the end of a raw triple quoted string fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

The below fails with syntax error:

```
chars = r'''|'*+[]".?!-/,{}()&%$_;:#@=`~<>^\'''
# SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
```

Switching the last two characters causes the code to work as expected:

```
chars = r'''|'*+[]".?!-/,{}()&%$_;:#@=`~<>\^'''
print("Output: " + ''.join(chars))     
# Output: |'*+[]".?!-/,{}()&%$_;:#@=`~<>\^
```

Is this a python implementation issue, or did I miss something?

Comment: add another backslash as you want to include the backslash

Comment: chars = r'''|'*+[]".?!-/,{}()&%$_;:#@=`~<>^\\'''

Comment: Interesting. The additional backslash does not help the raw triple quote string

Comment: Searched SO and found this.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870730/python-raw-strings-and-trailing-backslash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been documented on [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash) documentation. So you can read through the details.

Extract from the FAQ:

- Why can’t raw strings (r-strings) end with a backslash? More
  precisely, they can’t end with an odd number of backslashes: the
  unpaired backslash at the end escapes the closing quote character,
  leaving an unterminated string.
- Raw strings were designed to ease creating input for processors
  (chiefly regular expression engines) that want to do their own
  backslash escape processing. Such processors consider an unmatched
  trailing backslash to be an error anyway, so raw strings disallow
  that. In return, they allow you to pass on the string quote character
  by escaping it with a backslash. These rules work well when r-strings
  are used for their intended purpose.

Unfortunately there is no way around it. You need to end it with another character or include a space. If you include a space, the length will change.

The trick to get the backslash as the last string is to add a space after the backslash.

```
char = r'''|'*+[]".?!-/,{}()&%$_;:#@=`~<>^\ '''
print ('last char:',char[-1], 'second last char', char[-2],'third last char', char[-3])
```

Here's the output of the above code:

```
last char:   second last char \ third last char ^
```

So you have to just change it to another character. The reason is `\` is an escape character and it is taking the `'` as a char.

My initial reaction was to add another backslash. However, that just adds the backslash to the string. See code below.

```
char = r'''|'*+[]".?!-/,{}()&%$_;:#@=`~<>^\\'''
print ('last char:',char[-1], 'second last char', char[-2],'third last char', char[-3])
```

The output is:

```
last char: \ second last char \ third last char ^
```

The only workaround I found is to include the space but to slice the string to [:-1]. You can do the following:

```
char = r'''|'*+[]".?!-/,{}()&%$_;:#@=`~<>^\ '''[:-1]
print ('last char:',char[-1], 'second last char', char[-2],'third last char', char[-3])
```

The output of this will be:

```
last char: \ second last char ^ third last char >
```

Comment: I would be interested to know why I was downvoted. Happy to learn and improve

Comment: Primarily because there's nothing special about putting a space after the backslash as opposed to any other character (including another backslash). Particularly, putting a space there doesn't make the backslash the last character, contrary to the line "The trick to get the backslash as the last string is to add a space after the backslash" in the answer.

Comment: Well, I think I did enough research and looked up documentation to ensure python does not have a way to solve for it. All that information has been shared in the answer. I will leave this answer this as is. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yeah this answers the question by linking the doc that I missed. The workaround (which slices using operator chars[:-1] with a space at the end) is mentioned in the FAQ that was linked as well